# How to count total number of particular word on the website?

Tags: python

I am developing a small program which goes through a website and find a a word based on user input and counts how many times the word has occurred on webpage.

Here is my try below:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class NeedstobeParser(HTMLParser):
    sites = []
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == "a":
            for attr in attrs:
                if attr[0] == "href":
                    self.sites.append(attr[1])

    def get_sites(self):
        return self.sites

website = urlopen('http://worldfacts.us')
html = website.read()
content = html.decode()

Parser = NeedstobeParser()
Parser.feed(content)
sites = Parser.get_sites()
country_sites = []


for countries in sites:
    countries = countries.replace("http://worldfacts.us/","")
    countries = countries.replace(".", "")
    countries = countries.replace("-", " ")
    countries = countries.replace("htm","")
    country_sites.append(countries)
country_sites.remove('map/index')
country_sites.remove('flag/index')

for i in country_sites:
    print(i)



while True:
    count_number = 0
    userinput = input("What country would you like to look up?: ")
    if userinput in country_sites:
        url = "http://worldfacts.us/"+userinput+".htm"
        askuser = input('What word would you like to look up?: ')
        for i in url:
            if askuser in url:
                count_number += 1
                print(count_number)
```

> ```
> #this second try instead of for loop
>             margo = url.count("'"+askuser+"'")
>             count_number = count_number + margo
> ```

```
        print("The word " + "'"+askuser+"'" + " shows up " + str(count_number) + " time(s) on " + url)
        break
    else:
        print('Error. '+ "'"+userinput+"'" +' not found.')
```

both of the tries give me '0' result but I am sure 100% that the word which user typed in is contains on the webpage.

Comment: hint: What is `for i in url` actually iterating over?

Comment: @gla3dr over this link "http://worldfacts.us/"+userinput+".htm"

Comment: Ah, but Python doesn't know that is a link. To python it's just a string. Consider this: getting the page for a specific country works just like getting the worldfacts.us homepage with the list of all the countries. What did you do to get the homepage that you aren't doing to get the country's page? If it helps, try printing out `i` in your for loop and see if it matches what you are expecting it to be.

Comment: @gla3dr thank you so much, I finally figured it out. Appreciate it